# How to convert string reponse to json in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have tried this many times with different suggestions but still the error "unexpected token s" is coming...

i am giving a post request with json as an argument and back-end method returns "SUCCESS" as result of successful completion of request.

post request:

```
$http.post(UPDATE_COMMENT_FOR_ISSUE_URL, json, {
    headers: {
        "Token": Token, 
        "csrfParam": getCookieClosePortal(),
         "transformResponse":function (data, headers,status) {
                 alert("data is"+data+" "+headers+" "+status);
                 //alert("data is"+response.data.token)
               // data = {"data":data};
               data={"status" : "success"};
            return data;
            },
            responseType : "text"
    }})
    .then(function(response)
    {
        alert('res '+response);});
```

alert gives [object object] undefined undefined

but in network it shows 200 status

Comment: You can see more via console.log()
Then observe the structure of the response object

Answer (score 0):

Remove `transformResponse` and `responseType`, receive the pure response into `then` method and call `console.log(response)` instead of `alert` it.
there are too much useless code and it doesn't help you to find the mistake. Be clearer to tell where and how this *unexpected token s* erros is happening because it is not clear just by looking the piece of code you have posted.

Comment: Don't you receive nothing by calling `.success(...)` either?

Comment: i hv tried that too but the control is not going to success too